# For --module should I use amd or commonjs?

Tags: requirejs, typescript, js-amd

When I put "**export** module" in a .ts file, it says I need to add --module.

That requires a KIND. If I'm using TypeScript, RequireJS, and Ext JS, is amd the correct kind?

Comment: Check out this video tutorial : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) is what RequireJS expects.